# Ruby on rails with ajax

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

i used ajax for country state city selection on my ruby on rails project, i used

```
            <% city_opts = [["Select a city","0"]]
               @cities.sort_by{|h| h["name"]}.each{|c|
               city_opts << [c["name"],c["id"]]
               }
            %>
            <label class="create-play-fix-label" style="color: grey; font-size: 12px;" for="city">
              City<span class="color-red required">*</span>
            </label> <%=@country%> <%=@state%>
            <%= select_tag "e_city", options_for_select(city_opts,"#{@event['city']}"), :onchange => "event_city_changed()" %>
```

please help me to put Selected value at `options_for_select` method for my update flow. thanks in advance.

Comment: The second argument of `options_for_select` is the selected value, which (in your case) is the city's id (maybe `@event['city']` is not returning the id but the city's name?)

Comment: Thanks for reply...., Yeah ,@event['city'] is the city's name. i want to show my selected city's name in that field. but it is not working...